# Block indent jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Does anyone know how to get a command shortcut to work for block indenting and un-indenting in Jupyter notebooks?
 
In the Jupiter notebook command group there is a command “automatically indent selection”. When I put in a command mode control-/  for that command the notebook does block commenting. 
 
 
I don’t see any other command that refers to indenting.
 
I can’t seem to figure this

Comment: For me, selecting multiple lines and doing tab (for indenting) and shift+tab (for removing indenting) works. Does it not work for you?

Comment: It does.  Thanks.  Didn't know it does that.

Comment: An additional useful hotkey, is `ctrl + /`.  This automatically comments and indents or un-comments and un-indents the selected line(s).

Answer (score 68):

it's

> Tab

If you want to unindent, then

> Shift + Tab

You need to have selected more rows or it's intellisense...

Comment: If you have installed extensions, then you can edit shortcuts as you like...

Comment: This has the side effect that converts the font to monospaced font. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I use default, so i haven't noticed. You can change any shortcode in Edit command mode keyboard shortcuts command, but indentation is not there. Maybe bug i guess...?

Comment: This seems to cancel out any Latex in the indented block.

Comment: In JupyterLab Version 1.2.3 does not work for unindenting.

Answer (score 7):

In JupyterLab,`ctrl+[` and `ctrl+]` work for indentation/deindentation.

These solutions also are guaranteed to work, whereas `Tab` and `Shift+Tab` can trigger actions like intellisense if your cursor is in the middle of a line.